# Display the prime numbers using multi-threading in C

Tags: c, multithreading, primes

In the function `printprime`, I am iterating over each element with each of the four threads, this is almost equivalent to a single threaded program. I want to increment `i` by `i=i+MAX_THREADS`. I am using four threads as my Laptop has four processors and it is fully optimized. Can someone tell me how to tweak the `printprime` so that each thread iterates over a single digit. Like, thread 1 checks 2, 6, 10... thread2 checks 3, 7, 11... and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 30
#define MAX_THREADS 4

int prime_arr[N] = { 0 };

void *printprime(void *ptr) {
    int j, flag;
    int i = (int)(long long int)ptr;
    for (i = 2; i < N; i++) {
        flag = 0;
        for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            prime_arr[i] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid[MAX_THREADS] = {{ 0 }};
    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < MAX_THREADS; count++) {
        printf("\r\n CREATING THREADS %d", count);
        pthread_create(&tid[count], NULL, printprime, (void *)count);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (count = 0; count < MAX_THREADS; count++) {
        pthread_join(tid[count], NULL);
    }

    int c = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < N; count++)
        if (prime_arr[count] == 1)
            printf("%d ", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: before using 200 threads, don't loop until `for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)`use `for(j=2;j<=int(sqrt(i));j++)` and you'll save some CPU... also this isn't the most efficient way: sieve of erathostenes could interest you.

Comment: If you declare a function to return something, then you should actually return something from the function, or you will have *undefined behavior*. Just adding a `return NULL` at the end of your thread function is enough.

Comment: Also,  for maximum portability and standard C compliance typecast the argument to the thread function through `intptr_t`. Like `(void *) (intptr_t) count` when calling `pthread_create`; And `i = (int) (inptr_t) ptr` inside the thread function.

Comment: I actually want to know how to make sure that each thread accesses only one element of the prime_arr and that too once. In the above code, each thread accesses each element. This means each element undergoes scrutiny fur times.

Comment: What happens if you compile with strict warnings? E.g. `gcc -Wall`. Consider checking only up to sqrt(i) (rounded up), instead of wasting performance by checking unitl (i/2). That might be more benefit than anything you can achieve by multithreading, at least for large N. Probably on top of Erathostenes.

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved . :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'a single digit'? How is 10 a single digit?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- all threads use `for (i = 2; i < N; i++)` so they perform exactly the same scan, testing the same numbers... You get no advantage from using multiple threads.
- the name `printprime` is very confusing for a function that scans for prime numbers but does not print them.
- you modify the same array in multiple threads without synchronisation: this has undefined behavior if the same element is accessed from different threads and if the element size is smaller than the atomic size.
- even if the code was modified for each thread to test the subset you document in the question, this would be very inefficient as every other threads would end up testing only even numbers.
- the loop `for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++)` iterates far too long for prime numbers. You should stop when `j * j > i`, which can be tested as `for (j = 2; i / j <= j; j++)`.
- even with this optimisation, trial division is very inefficient to populate the `prime_arr` array. Implementing a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is far superior and much more appropriate for a multithreading approach.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define N 10000000
#define MAX_THREADS 4

unsigned char prime_arr[N];

void *scanprime(void *ptr) {
    int n, i, j, flag, start, stop;
    n = (int)(intptr_t)ptr;
    start = N / MAX_THREADS * n;
    stop = N / MAX_THREADS * (n + 1);
    if (start < 2)
        start = 2;
    if (n == MAX_THREADS - 1)
        stop = N;
    for (i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        flag = 1;
        for (j = 2; i / j >= j; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        prime_arr[i] = flag;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *sieveprimes(void *ptr) {
    int n, i, j, start, stop;
    n = (int)(intptr_t)ptr;
    /* compute slice boundaries */
    start = N / MAX_THREADS * n;
    stop = N / MAX_THREADS * (n + 1);
    /* special case 0, 1 and 2 */
    if (n == 0) {
        prime_arr[0] = prime_arr[1] = 0;
        prime_arr[2] = 1;
        start = 3;
    }
    if (n == MAX_THREADS - 1) {
        stop = N;
    }
    /* initialize array slice: only odd numbers may be prime */
    for (i = start; i < stop; i++) {
        prime_arr[i] = i & 1;
    }
    /* set all multiples of odd numbers as composite */
    for (j = 3; j * j < N; j += 2) {
        /* start at first multiple of j inside the slice */
        i = (start + j - 1) / j * j;
        /* all multiples below j * j have been cleared already */
        if (i < j * j)
            i = j * j;
        /* only handle odd multiples */
        if ((i & 1) == 0)
            i += j;
        for (; i < stop; i += j + j) {
            prime_arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t tid[MAX_THREADS] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        printf("Creating thread %d\n", i);
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, sieveprimes, (void *)(intptr_t)i);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        count += prime_arr[i];
        //if (prime_arr[i] == 1)
        //    printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve desirable, increment variable `i` in function `void *printprime(void *ptr)` by `MAX_THREADS`(4 in your case).

**Note:** Line `printf("Thread id[%d] checking [%d]\n",pthread_self(),i);` is used to show that which thread is checking which value.

Following code may be helpful:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define N 30
#define MAX_THREADS 4

int prime_arr[N]={0};

void *printprime(void *ptr)
{
    int  j,flag;
    int i=(int)(long long int)ptr;
    while(i<N)
    {
        printf("Thread id[%d] checking [%d]\n",pthread_self(),i);
        flag=0;
        for(j=2;j<=i/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag==0 && (i>1))
        {
            prime_arr[i]=1;
        }
        i+=MAX_THREADS;
  }
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[MAX_THREADS]={{0}};
    int count=0;
    for(count=0;count<MAX_THREADS;count++)
    {
        printf("\r\n CREATING THREADS %d",count);
        pthread_create(&tid[count],NULL,printprime,(void*)count);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(count=0;count<MAX_THREADS;count++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[count],NULL);
    }

    int c=0;
    for(count=0;count<N;count++)
        if(prime_arr[count]==1)
            printf("%d ",count);

    return 0;
 }
```